# Cannot open include file: 'QTimer': No such file or directory

Tags: qt, gstreamer, qtimer

I am trying to run a code available on https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/qt-gstreamer/html/examples_2player_2main_8cpp-example.html

But when I try to run the code I get following error.

Cannot open include file: 'QTimer': No such file or directory.

What should I do??

Comment: Post your *.pro file, please.

Comment: Have you installed qt ? Is in the same directory as the example ? If not have you tried adding an include directory to your project ? What have you tried ?

Comment: Actually I am new to g streamer. I dont know what is .pro file

Comment: I havent installed qt on my machine. Can you suggest how to do that?

Comment: Please post a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](/help/mcve).  In this case, that is probably a source file containing just `#include <QTimer>` and a Makefile (or your compilation command).

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to install the [Open Source version of Qt](http://www.qt.io/download-open-source/)

Then, create a new `Qt` project from the `Qt Creator` IDE and add your files (.cpp, .h, etc.).

I also strongly advise you to read the [Getting Started part of the Qt documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/gettingstarted.html)